# obtaining last value of dataframe column without index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Suppose I have a DataFrame such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5), columns = ['a','b','c','d','e'])
```

and I would like to retrieve the last value in column `e`. I could do:

```
df['e'].tail(1)
```

but this would return a series which has index 9 with it. Ideally, I just want to obtain the value as a number that I can work with directly. I could also do:

```
np.array(df['e'].tail(1))
```

but this would then require me to access/call the 0'th element of it before I can really work with it. Is there a more direct/easy way to do this?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You could try [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) method of dataframe:

```
In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
          a         b         c         d         e
0 -1.079547 -0.722903  0.457495 -0.687271 -0.787058
1  1.326133  1.359255 -0.964076 -1.280502  1.460792
2  0.479599 -1.465210 -0.058247 -0.984733 -0.348068
3 -0.608238 -1.238068 -0.126889  0.572662 -1.489641
4 -1.533707 -0.218298 -0.877619  0.679370  0.485987
5 -0.864651 -0.180165 -0.528939  0.270885  1.313946
6  0.747612 -1.206509  0.616815 -1.758354 -0.158203
7 -2.309582 -0.739730 -0.004303  0.125640 -0.973230
8  1.735822 -0.750698  1.225104  0.431583 -1.483274
9 -0.374557 -1.132354  0.875028  0.032615 -1.131971

In [27]: df['e'].iloc[-1]
Out[27]: -1.1319705662711321
```

Or if you want just scalar you could use [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) which is faster. From [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting):

> If you only want to access a scalar value, the fastest way is to use the `at` and `iat` methods, which are implemented on all of the data structures

```
In [28]: df.e.iat[-1]
Out[28]: -1.1319705662711321
```

Benchmarking:

```
In [31]: %timeit df.e.iat[-1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 18 µs per loop

In [32]: %timeit df.e.iloc[-1]
10000 loops, best of 3: 24 µs per loop
```

Comment: I get "no axis named -1 for object type Series"

Comment: @cikatomo are you sure that you are using `iloc` but not `loc`?

Comment: @cikatomo I think your problem is because you are probably using `iat(-1)` or `iloc(-1)`, and you have to use `iat[-1]` or `iloc[-1]`. I had the same problem and I solved it using correctly both methods. I mean using brackets (`[ ]`) and not parentheses (`( )`).

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
df['e'].iloc[[-1]]
```

Sometimes,

```
df['e'].iloc[-1]
```

doesn't work.

Comment: but it still returns the Series object, how to get the value only?

Comment: Use iat function instead of iloc

Answer (score 1):

We can also access it by indexing `df.index` and `at`:

```
df.at[df.index[-1], 'e']
```

It's faster than `iloc` but slower than without indexing.

If we decide to assign a value to the last element in column "e", the above method is much faster than the other two options (9-11 times faster):

````
>>> %timeit df.at[df.index[-1], 'e'] = 1
11.5 µs ± 355 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %timeit df['e'].iat[-1] = 1
107 µs ± 4.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

>>> %timeit df['e'].iloc[-1] = 1
127 µs ± 7.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)```
````