# Get last value of each columns in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166030/obtaining-last-value-of-dataframe-column-without-index/34166097), I know how to get the last value of a column. But I want a list/series of all the last values of every columns. Easy way is to iterate over each columns and do something like this -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5), columns = ['a','b','c','d','e'])
l = []
for col in df.columns.values:
    l.append(df[col].iloc[-1])
```

But I am looking for more pythonic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select last row:

```
print (df.iloc[-1])
```

If need list:

```
print (df.iloc[-1].tolist())
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(2021)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5), columns = ['a','b','c','d','e'])
print (df)

l = []
for col in df.columns.values:
    l.append(df[col].iloc[-1])
print (l)
[1.2242357215843627, -0.5456577180464415, 0.9067480525839758, -0.9826172361069304, -0.6331618916225082]

print (df.iloc[-1].tolist())
[1.2242357215843627, -0.5456577180464415, 0.9067480525839758, -0.9826172361069304, -0.6331618916225082]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code line please:

```py
df.iloc[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `tail` on the whole frame:

```
df.tail(1)
```

Or to get a Series use `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list:

```
df.iloc[-1].tolist()
```