# Accessing imported data from Excel in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm new to python and just trying to redo my first project from matlab. I've written a code in vscode to import an excel file using pandas

```
filename=r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\data.xlsx'
sheet=['data']
with pd.ExcelFile(filename) as xls:
  Dateee=pd.read_excel(xls, sheet,index_col=0)
```

Then I want to access data in a row and column.

I tried to print data using code below:

```
for key in dateee.keys():
   print(dateee.keys())
```

but this returns nothing.
Is there anyway to access the data (as a list)?

Comment: `Dateee` is a DataFrame, not a dictionary.

Comment: It seems like you are asking for conflicting infomration here. key and dateee.key() are dict options. Are you simply trying to read the excel file?

Comment: Plus you are mixing lower case and upper case.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on each column, making the contents of each a list:

```py
for c in df:
    print(df[c].to_list())
```

`df` is what the dataframe was assigned as. (OP had inconsistent syntax & so I didn't use that.)

Look into `df.iterrows()` or `df.itertuples()` if you want to iterate by row.  Example:

```py
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row)
```

Look into `df.iloc` and `df.loc` for row and column selection of individual values, see [Pandas iloc and loc – quickly select rows and columns in DataFrames](https://www.shanelynn.ie/pandas-iloc-loc-select-rows-and-columns-dataframe/).

Or `df.iat` or `df.at` for getting or setting single values, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html), [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html#pandas.DataFrame.at), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166097/8508004).

Comment: Thanks so much. I will try it.