# evaluate last character of column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following sentence in Python:

`df['isTrue'] = np.where(df['colname'][-1] in ['R', 'V'], True, False)`

But it is raising this error: `KeyError: -1`

How can I evaluate the last character of a column value?

Comment: Does it answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71491577/17521785

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with `isin`,notice you do not need `np.where` here, check the the 2nd line

```
df['isTrue'] = np.where(df['colname'].str[-1].isin(['R', 'V']), True, False)
#df['isTrue'] = df['colname'].str[-1].isin(['R', 'V'])
```